# 2002 Suburban overheating

Tags: chevrolet, overheating, suburban

2002 Suburban 5.3 random over heating new thermostat and housing,sensor,cap,clutch fan,no water in oil. all started with loss of heat and air heater blew ice cold had to recharge air to get cold air new thermostat brought back the heat but still when driving on a hot day overheats.

Comment: Maybe radiator is clogged enough to  overheat.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When was the last time (if ever) you flushed the Dexcool out and replaced?